# Revit model locked after relinquishing ownership through Revit API with a BIM360 project

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-bim360

We have a process where we check out all elements in the Revit model using worksharing to make sure everything is available when processing the data. After processing the data, then it's time to relinquish all the elements again but here we get an error when doing this on larger projects on BIM360.

The method used to relinquish the elements is this one:

```cs
var relinquishOptions = new RelinquishOptions(true);

try
{
    // Relinquish everything
    WorksharingUtils.RelinquishOwnership(doc, relinquishOptions, null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MsgBox.ShowMsg(e.ToString(), "Relinquish ownership failed");
    throw;
}
```

This triggers this error message on the "sync with central" dialog from BIM360:

After this the model can't be synced with the central model on BIM360. Using the Revit API to sync with central we get this exception:

`Autodesk.revit.Exceptions.CentralModelContentionException: The central model is being accessed by another client.`

The model is locked by our user and the only way to "unblock" it is by reuploading the file to BIM360.

This only happens on files on BIM360 and only on larger files. The file is around 350MB.

### Are we missing something?

I can't seem to find any documentation on RevitAPI mentioning any restrictions on the integration with BIM360 that could explain the issue.
Do any of you know why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you saying the issue happens only for large files, but works good with normal size file?

Comment: @ZhongWu Exactly! We've been using this procedure for some time but it has only shown issues when working on large files.

Comment: The development team took a look at the issue and would like to analyse in more depth. They ask for a [reproducible case](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b) and a journal file. Could you provide that, please?

Comment: @JeremyTammik , re:reproducible case:
Yes, we agree, we have already submitted the reproducible case 10-27-2021 12:45.
It is in 
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-model-locked-after-relinquishing-ownership-through-revit/m-p/10716518/highlight/true#M59329

Do you want the case here as well? Otherwise let us know where we can submit it? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I grabbed the reproducible case from the Revit API discussion forum thread and passed it on to the development team.